# Search for a specific value in a specific column with Python

Tags: python

I've got a text file that is tab delimited and I'm trying to figure out how to search for a value in a specific column in this file.

I think i need to use the csv import but have been unsuccessful so far. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**Update**
Thanks for everyone's updates. I know I could probably use awk for this but simply for practice, I am trying to finish it in python.

I am getting the following error now:
if row.split(' ')[int(searchcolumn)] == searchquery:
IndexError: list index out of range

And here is the snippet of my code:

```
#open the directory and find all the files
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        f=open(file, 'r')
        lines=f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            #the first 4 lines of the file are crap, skip them
            if linescounter > startfromline:
                with open(file) as infile:
                    for row in infile:
                        if row.split(' ')[int(searchcolumn)] == searchquery:
                            rfile = open(resultsfile, 'a')
                            rfile.writelines(line) 
                            rfile.write("\r\n")
                            print "Writing line -> " + line
                            resultscounter += 1
        linescounter += 1
        f.close()
```

I am taking both searchcolumn and searchquery as raw_input from the user. Im guessing the reason I am getting the list out of range now, is because it's not parsing the file correctly?

Thanks again.

Comment: If this isn't part of a larger Python app, you may find that this is the sort of thing that `awk` was made for.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the sniffer (example taken from http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

```
csvfile = open("example.csv", "rb")
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
csvfile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll want to use the csv module, and you'll want to set delimiter to '\t':

```
spamReader = csv.reader(open('spam.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
```

After that you should be able to iterate:

```
for row in spamReader:
   print row[n]
```

Comment: But what if I want to ask the user for a "searchcolumn" so that I can search for values on a specific column....not in a row.

Comment: The above will let you search the column. `if row[n] == searchterm: #do something.`

Answer (score 0):

This prints all rows in `filename` with 'myvalue' in the fourth tab-delimited column:

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    for row in infile:
        if row.split('\t')[3] == 'myvalue':
            print row
```

Replace 3, 'myvalue', and `print` as appropriate.